# What LaunchConfiguration for Fargate?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

An AutoScalingGroup needs a LaunchConfiguration

The problem is that the LaunchConfiguration requires things like ImageId and other parameters which I do not have since I am using containers.

How should the LaunchConfiguration be configured when using ECS Fargate?

AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html

AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html

Comment: Are you looking for [service autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html) instead of ec2 autoscaling, which is only concerned with starting/stopping instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example of a FARGATE autoscaling policy, that, as you can see, does not involve Launch Configuration nor Auto Scaling Groups. You just have to insert the `ScalingTargetId`, and since we'll be using a Target Tracking Scaling Policy, the infrastructure will grant you to have a system with a target of 80% maximum CPU usage. When the usage will be more than that, autoscaling will occur.

```
ExampleCPUAutoScalingPolicy:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyName: ECSCPUAutoScalingPolicy
    PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
    ScalingTargetId: !Ref ECSTarget
    TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
      DisableScaleIn: false
      TargetValue: 80
      ScaleInCooldown: 60
      ScaleOutCooldown: 60
      PredefinedMetricSpecification:
        PredefinedMetricType: ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this cloud formation stack.it supported both EC2/FARGATE

https://github.com/shakyasunil/aws/blob/master/cloudformation/ecs_service.json

with this required parameter

```
TaskDefinitionName
ECSServiceRoleARN
ECSAutoscalingRoleARN
```

Answer (score 0):

Fargate does not require an Auto Scaling Group or Launch Configuration as Fargate manages the underlying infrastructure directly.