# Amazon AWS Fargate Task static IP adress

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

During migration on AWS, I created a new cluster on AWS and deployed several docker application with Fargate approach.
During each update of task definition, new task is launched inside service and new public IP is assigned from AWS public IP pool

Is there any solution or instruction on how I can attach static IP adderes to the service tasks?

I saw similar question here 
[How do I associate an Elastic IP with a Fargate container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894034/how-do-i-associate-an-elastic-ip-with-a-fargate-container)

but still can't find any solution

Comment: Can you please add some more detail to the context of your application? What type of workloads do you plan on running inside aws fargate? Depending on your workload, I would imagine you will find that your best would be to set up an application load balancer connected to your aws-fargate service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392830/what-launchconfiguration-for-fargate/48809229#48809229)

add application load balancer to your fargate service.
service auto scaling is bettor approach to do this.

Comment: The only problem is that ALB cost approximately the same price as Fargate task - so for one fargate task you actually have price*2

Comment: Did you try network load balancer? Somehow I feel fargate has to mature.

Comment: Load balancer is not a solution, because it changes its IP from time to time, not very often, for me it happens once per 2 months and we had some bugs because of that.