# AWS Fargate task definition static IP address

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

There is a similar discussion about this but i have got a different scenario.

[Amazon AWS Fargate Task static IP adress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887504/amazon-aws-fargate-task-static-ip-adress)

In my case, i need a static IP so i can whitelist it at my database server firewall which is NOT hosted in AWS.

Any solution for this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).